# Как удалить темную тему в приложении android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Как удалить темную тему в приложении? Удаление night.theme не помогло. Так же не помогает в каждом активити и фрагменте прописывать отключение темной темы в коде.

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Comment: А эта проблема - на всех девайсах? Если только на Xiomi - попробуйте в стилях прописать запрет на принудительное включение тёмной темы. Что-то типа `forceDarkModeAllowed`

Comment: Огромное спасибо, прописал в теме для 29 апи и выше forceDarkModeAllowed = false и проблема решилась

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема часто встречается на Xiomi - попробуйте в стилях прописать запрет на принудительное включение тёмной темы.

```
<item name="forceDarkModeAllowed">false<item/>
```